# Why does my Python freeze when I do an overflow calculation?

Tags: python, math, freeze

I'm a MATLAB user trying to understand Python so sorry if this is obvious.

If I say

```
print(9**9)
```

I get:
387420489

Great.

If I say `print(9**9**9)`
Python just sits there indefinitely and freezes (I use Spyder version 4). Ctrl-C doesn't stop it.
Why does it not just immediately return Inf? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: What do you expect the output of `print(9**9**9)` to be?

Comment: Inf or the maximum integer 2147483647 (for  or int32) in any case, return something, don't just sit there.

Comment: What has `(9**9**9)` got to do with `Inf or the maximum integer 2147483647`?

Comment: python uses big integers.

Comment: It's probably trying to print it

Comment: python tries harder to give you a result. it automatically increases the precision for integers if needed.
To verify @PeterWood s hypothesis implement the code in two lines with an intermediate print:
a = 9 ** 9 ** 9
print("calculated a")
print(a)

Comment: btw, I'm expecting that `(9**9**9)` to be interpreted as `(9**(9**9))` which is `(9**387420489)`, That's quite large. And `((9**9)**9)` is the quite small number: `196627050475552913618075908526912116283103450944214766927315415537966391196809` which python seems to calculate instantly.

Comment: If I got an Inf, I would immediately know I probably did something wrong. Even if I got some large number, I could at least trace it and verify it (for example, compare it to "9 ** 9 ** 8.99" and see it I got the same thing. If I did, then I know I saturated somewhere). If it doesn't do anything, well, then I have to restart and lose a lot of time. As I said, I'm a MATLAB guy trying to learn Python, so there are probably lots of "design decisions" that don't immediately make sense to me, but if anyone has insight into this behavior, and why it's preferred, I'd really like to understand it.

Comment: This behavior came up when I was trying to naively calculate n choose k, where I knew for sure the answer would be larger than the maximum integer and didn't really care. I had expected it to just return Inf or something, but instead it froze, so I was thrown off.

Comment: The upper bound of a python integer is limited only by your memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the num `9**9**9` is very big to caculated
you can wait untill it will return a result
it can take much long time

Comment: I accept that your answer is correct. From my perspective, it seems to be odd behavior. This was a trivial, contrived example, but if I was developing a much more complicated algorithm, should I expect that Python will freeze every time I have some bug that introduces an overflow calculation?

Comment: you keep claiming it froze. it is still calculating. also a general purpose language can not take the same shortcut as a algebra engine. Your perspective is just one. Python must offer solutions to other use cases as well that can't make use of any such shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

When doing numerical calculations with integers, python is **not** limited to machine-specific numbers such as "int32", and therefore a number such as "2147483647" does not mean much to it. Instead, it uses a "big integer" library, which can, in principle, express any large number, provided there is enough memory for it. When facing a computation such as `9**9**9` python tries to perform it *exactly*, producing the exact result, however big it may be. For this particular calculation it just takes a lot of time (and memory, presumably internally python is trying to allocate more and more memory as needed).

Answer (score 0):

> Why does my Python freeze when I do an overflow calculation?

because no overflow occurred and python hasn't given up. Python will extend the precision until either the calculation succeeds or the machine runs out of memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes 100% logical sense. I'm just trying to wrap my head around the practical design decision of why this would be useful as opposed to another type of behavior that explicitly just informs you of a (potential) overflow condition.

Comment: @tomiyama: What really is the difference between python reporting overflow or python reporting "out of memory". The latter is in fact more correct since it provides more information. You can easily choose to interpret that "out of memory" as "overflow" if you choose to. Also, there is no way for python to determine in advance which calculations will exceed the memory limit. It can only attempt the calculation and see what happens.